# php if page doesn't exist display 404

Tags: php, html, variables, include

I have a code I'm trying to make work. Excuse my ignorance, I'm trying to learn but I can't find anything that specifically helps me.

What I want to do is:

On my index, display show_news.php

When `index.php?page=blank` is used, display the contents of `blank.php`

and if the chosen page doesn't exist I want to display a custom 404 page. Say if `blank2.php` was used and doesn't exist it includes `404.php`

The 404 page is what I'm struggling with.

```
<?php
$number = 4;
if(!$_GET[page]){ 
    include "show_news.php"; 
} elseif ($_GET[page]) { 
    include $_GET[page].".php"; 
} else { 
    include "404.php"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: The logic in your `if` condition makes no sense

Comment: It will never reach the `else` statement

Comment: See, this is where I need help haha. I'm still a youngster when it comes to this. How will it not reach the else? I thought the order is supposed to be "if, elseif, else"

Comment: Variables don't magically check the existence of files, your need [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) for that.  Also what your doing is [insecure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Local_File_Inclusion).

Comment: Alright, this is all Latin to me. I'll do more studying and find a more secure way to do what I need to do, and correctly.

Comment: Never trust user input. You can check it against strings, and then perform operations on the file system with strings you specify, but don't use user-supplied variables for much of anything without sanitizing them. Your code would allow the user to include any file in your file-system by passing the right value for "page" (if you were also accessing the superglobal value properly with `$_GET['page']`)

Answer (score 0):

try to use file_exists() function
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php

```
<?php
$number = 4;
define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__);
$project_path = ROOTPATH . "/path/to/page/files/";
$page = $_GET["page"];
$is_file_existing = $file_exists($project_path . $page . ".php");
if(!$page){
    include "show_news.php";
} elseif ($is_file_existing) {
    include $page . ".php";
} else {
    include "404.php";
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried this, and got an error.

"Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/****/public_html/news/index.php on line 79"

Line 79 being the

`$is_file_existing = $file_exists($project_path . $page . ".php");` line


Googling shows there's an errant $, removing it from `file_exists` removes the error but then it works like my original code

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get your question.
But here's how I would do it:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
    include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php');
else
    include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/show_news.php');
```

Then in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**Edit:**
Make use of **mysqli_real_escape_string** before passing it in to **$_GET**.